# Plotting a legend using legend(x,y ....) but x axis are dates in R

Tags: r, line, legend, legend-properties

I'm trying to put a legend on a line graph using legend(x,y, legend=c("","").... etc. I've changed the date to numeric data and used that for x and it plots, so I know the rest of its right. but when x is a date I'm not sure what to use for x to get the legend to show on the graph.
thanks

Comment: The simplest is `x = as.numeric([date here])` or using the keywords `"topright"`, `"bottomright"`, `"bottomleft"` or `"topleft"` rather than x,y. eg. `legend("bottomright", ...)`.

Comment: Thank you I've sorted it